# Bootstrap font colour lighter than background colour

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Bootstrap now does a good job at showing navbar item colours that are dynamically muted from the colour of the navbar behind it.

Is it possible to take advantage of the same approach in body text?

ie. If a container background is purple, have the text colour be white but slightly on the purple scale?

Maybe text-muted should do it, but that always seems to be grey.

Comment: can you please explain what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't have this feature built in, but a little CSS should make it possible.

Use something like this:

```
.special-text{
   color: white;
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

`opacity` makes the text slightly transparent, so in your case it would be a bit purpleish.

Comment: Aha, opacity, brilliant.